# Best practice Delegation && Data source patterns

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my iPad Application, I have a leftBar like the navigation Bar by it is placed in the left vertically, this bar have many buttons and title.

The leftBar is added to the mainView ( my application has a RootViewController and the leftBar is added to the root's view). The leftBar is visible in all the application navigations views. To allow all other object ( controller ) to customize the Bar, i have created a Data source and a Delegate protocols in two methodes.

My question is : Am I using delegation and Data source patterns correctly? Which is the correct method (1 or 2) ? or the two methods are bad and there is a best solution to do this ?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol ToolBarDataSource <NSObject>

@optional

/** Asks the data source of the origin of the view
 @disscussion overide thid methode if yoy want différente origin
 of the view, the default is '(0,0)'
 */
- (CGPoint)toolBarViewOrigin;

/** Asks the data source for the backgounnd image for the view
 @Disscussion The toolBar view has a background image by default
 implemente this methode to customize it
 */
- (UIImage *)toolBarBackgroundImage;

/** Asks the data source for the frame for the button spécified with the tag
 @param buttonTag The button tag
 */
- (CGRect)toolBarButtonFrameWithTag:(NSUInteger)buttonTag;

/** Asks the data source for the button title spécified with the tag
 @param buttonTag The button tag
 */
- (NSString *)toolBarTitleForButtonWithTag:(NSUInteger)buttonTag;

/** Asks the data source for the button title font spécified with the tag
  @param buttonTag The button tag
*/
- (UIFont *)toolBarTitleFontForButtonWithTag:(NSUInteger)buttonTag;

/** Asks the data source for the button title text color spécified with the tag
@param buttonTag The button tag
*/
- (UIColor *)toolBarTitleColorForButtonWithTag:(NSUInteger)buttonTag;

/** Asks the data source to return the title to be displayed in the toolBar*/
- (NSString *)titleForToolBar;

/** Asks the data source to return the frame of the title label */
- (CGRect)toolBarTitleFrame;

@end


@protocol ToolBarDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

/** Tells the delegate that a button in the toolBar has been clicked
 @param buttonTag The button tag
 @disscussion Each button int the tollBar View is identified with a Tag.
 @see Constant.h for more details for all the tags
 */
- (void)toolBarButtonClickedWithTag:(NSUInteger)buttonTag;

@end


@interface ToolBarVC : UIViewController
/** The object that acts as the delegate of the receiving toolBar view. */
@property (nonatomic, assign)id <ToolBarDelegate>toolBarDelegate;

/** The object that acts as the data source of the receiving toolBar view. */
@property (nonatomic, assign)id <ToolBarDataSource>toolBarDataSource;

@end
```

Methode 2:

in this methode i have created in the delaget methode like this :

```
@protocol ToolBarDelegate <NSObject>

 @optional
- (void)setToolBarTitle:(NSString *)title
                   font:(UIFont *)font
                  color:(UIColor *)color
                  frame:(CGRect)frame;


/** */
- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image
                           title:(NSString *)title
                           color:(UIColor *)color
                           frame:(CGRect)frame;


/** */
- (void)setRightButtonBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image
                               title:(NSString *)title
                               color:(UIColor *)color
                               frame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing it right

**Method 1**

Pros:

- To set up each and everything i got  method.
- Gives flexibility for future projects
- Better documented

Cons

- To setup toolbar you have to make and set all the methods.
- Too much code for that

**Method 2**

Pros:

- Sigle method will setup my toolbar [That is what i will look for]

Cons:

- To change a single property it is not possible

So all it matters is **how you are supposed to use it** .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what do you think about the Delegate/DataSource methode naming ?

Comment: datasource methods are for setting up the control and delegates are supposed to be the actions or results.Name doesnt matter but the following way is used in apple's code See tableview Datasource delegate methods